# Changing default directory structure in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, directory-structure

I am working on asp.net mvc project which is quite large in size. I am new to the MVC stuff.

As Asp.Net MVC have default folder structure Controller, Views or Model so can we change this structure. what if instead of Controller i have different folder? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it is possible to change the [`LocationFormats` of a view engine](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/06/27/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location.aspx), this isn't recommended as it messes with the  standard MVC conventions.

Instead, you should consider using [Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for each of your major 'modules' of functionality.

Your folder structure will then be similar to:

```
/(MVC Root)
/Areas
   /Sales
      /Controllers
      /Views
   /Financials
      /Controllers
      /Views
```

etc.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/06/27/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location.aspx So it means i have to write my own view engine and pass controller to it?? Just asking for knowledge. Plan to go with Areas

Comment: Areas is the way to go in 99% of all the situations I can think of.